# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process2

Tags: c#

The process cannot access the file 'D:\Projects\DRPE_NET\Sample.FluentNHibernate.UI\TemporaryFile\Param_17_03_2014\Param_17_03_2014.log' because it is being used by another process.

i think probably io or anything else please help me

```
string currentPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string sourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentPath, "TemporaryFile");
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, file_name);
string transfert = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentPath, "TransfertFiles");
string transfertFiles = System.IO.Path.Combine(transfert,"export_parametrage.bat");

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
{
   // delete files in directory
   string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
   foreach (string temp in files)
   {
      System.IO.File.Delete(temp);
   }
   // delete directories in directory
   string[] diry = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath);
   foreach (string temp in diry)
   {
      // delete files in directory of directory
      string sourcePath1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, temp);
      string[] files1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath1);
      foreach (string temp1 in files1)
      {
         System.IO.File.Delete(temp1);
      }
      System.IO.Directory.Delete(temp);
   }
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceFile);
}
else if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePath);
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceFile);
}
// le mot de passe
string inipath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentPath, "ConfigFile.ini");
IniFile ini = new IniFile(inipath);
string m_d_p = ini.IniReadValue("Transfert", "motDePasse");
string s_i_d = ini.IniReadValue("Transfert", "sid");
string user = ini.IniReadValue("Transfert", "user");
string parametre = user + "/" + m_d_p + "@" + s_i_d;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = transfertFiles;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "" + sourceFile + " " + file_name + " " + parametre;
p.Start();
I: if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourceFile))
   {
      string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFile);
      if (files.Count() == 2)
      {
        try
        {
           string t = file_name + ".log";
           StreamReader file = new 
           StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(sourceFile, t));
           p.Kill();
           file.Close();
           goto II;
        }
        catch
        {
           goto I;
        }
      }
      else
      {
         goto I;
      }
   }
II:



ConfigFile.ini

 [Transfert]
 motDePasse=rrrr
 sid=rrrr
 user=rrrr
 fromuser=rrrr



public class IniFile
{
    public string path;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string val, string filePath);
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
             string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
        int size, string filePath);

    /// <summary>
    /// INIFile Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <PARAM name="INIPath"></PARAM>
    public IniFile(string INIPath)
    {
        path = INIPath;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Write Data to the INI File
    /// </summary>
    /// <PARAM name="Section"></PARAM>
    /// Section name
    /// <PARAM name="Key"></PARAM>
    /// Key Name
    /// <PARAM name="Value"></PARAM>
    /// Value Name
    public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read Data Value From the Ini File
    /// </summary>
    /// <PARAM name="Section"></PARAM>
    /// <PARAM name="Key"></PARAM>
    /// <PARAM name="Path"></PARAM>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
    {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp,
                                        255, this.path);
        return temp.ToString();

    }
  }
```

Comment: could you please show us your class `IniFile`?

Comment: just a an class to read or write from an init file, it does work elsewhere

Comment: can you show that class?

Comment: I'm confused, what is your goal - to kill a process or to read a file?

Comment: Yes, what's the question? Why the file is in use or why that error?

Comment: to fix this code, obviously to read the file

Answer (score 2):

Replace This:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(sourceFile, t));
p.Kill();
file.Close();
```

WIth This:

```
using(StreamReader file = new StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(sourceFile,t)))
{
   p.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a file as follows:

```
string fileContents;
try
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(sourceFile, t), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (IOException)
{
    p.Kill();
    p.WaitForExit(1000);
    goto I;
}
```

Please note, that `Kill` method executes asynchronously, so you need to wait.